# Creating a period-flag where the ending date is based on an inconsistent holiday

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, dimensional-modeling

I'm working on a date dimension table for my business, including your standard date measurements as well as holidays. Something I'm trying to add is a flag for certain important periods for the business, such as summer break (let's say 5/25-8/15 for example). This is easy to do with set dates, like those. However, one period flag I want to add is "Mardi Gras Season". This starts on 01/06 every year, but only ends after Mardi Gras, which in turn is based on Easter's date. It's a complex calculation, to the point where I used a function I found online to add Easter and related holidays (including Mardi Gras) to a separate Holiday dimension, which I then merged with the date dimension into a Calendar view.

I want to write a code that says gives a flag of 'YES' if a date is between 01/06 and the Mardi Gras date of THAT year, but this is really stumping me.

I've tried the following subquery:

```
 MardiGrasFlag = 
CASE
 WHEN FORMAT([Date], 'MM/dd') BETWEEN '01/06' AND 
(SELECT FORMAT(d.[Date], 'MM/dd') 
 FROM dbo.DateDimension AS d
  LEFT JOIN dbo.HolidayDimension AS h ON d.[Date] = h.[Date] 
 WHERE [Holiday Text] = 'Mardi Gras') THEN 'YES'
```

However, this gives an error (as expected), since it pulls multiple results. I've tried adding TOP 1 to the query, but then it always uses the first Mardi Gras date from my table. I need something that checks the date in question's year and uses the Mardi Gras date for that same year, but cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just want the MAX date for the Mardigras period in each year? Also, I think you need to be using a correlated subquery e.g. something like this:

```
UPDATE dbo.DateDimension d
set d.MardiGrasFlag = 
CASE
 WHEN FORMAT(d.[Date], 'MM/dd') BETWEEN '01/06' AND 
 (SELECT MAX(FORMAT(h.[Date], 'MM/dd'))
  FROM dbo.HolidayDimension AS h ON 
  FORMAT(d.[Date], 'YYYY') = FORMAT(h.[Date], 'YYYY')
  AND h.[Holiday Text] = 'Mardi Gras'
 ) 
THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
```